# What's the other half of the "To unlock your phone" message?

Tags: lock-screens

I've got a phone (I believe a Nexus Huawei 6p) that has a half-broken (the right half) screen. After trying a few unsuccessful passwords the phone has the message "To unlock your phone," and then the rest of the screen is broken. Does anyone happen to know what the rest of the message is?

Comment: Not without seeing the first half I'm afraid. Depending on the lock variant, screens can look quite different. So maybe you can **[edit]** your question and include a "screenshot" (well, rather a photo of the screen in this case I guess – but you get the idea)?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/miui/comments/cfxbi9/having_problems_at_the_lockscreen_i_have_no

Comment: Thanks! Rebooting it did work. I think alecxs has the right one.